# Is the leading strand consistent in the same chromosome with multiple replication forks?

Tags: dna, dna-replication

If a chromosome has multiple origins or replication, do those origins necessarily pick the same DNA strand as leading and the same one as lagging, or can they be of opposite orientations, sending replication forks in opposite directions and therefore picking different leading vs lagging strands?

Answer (score 1):

Replication proceeds in both directions from a *single* origin of replication, so the same strand acts as both the leading or lagging strand for the two different replication forks.

[image]